# SAPUI5 model loading

Tags: javascript, sapui5

Is there some way how to know when model is loaded?

Example:

```
sap.ui.controller("myapp.MyViewController", {

    onInit: function() {
        this.router = sap.ui.core.UIComponent.getRouterFor(this);
        this.router.attachRoutePatternMatched(this._handleRouteMatched, this);
        this.model = sap.ui.getCore().byId("app").getModel("mymodel");
    },

    onAfterRendering: function() {
        console.log(this.model);
    }
...
```

In this case the model instance is defined, but it contains empty object, because no data is loaded.

If I wrap the console.log method with:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(sap.ui.getCore().byId("app").getModel("mymodel"));
}, 0);
```

then model data gets loaded correctly, but I would like something more reliable than using setTimeout.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The class [sap.ui.model.Model](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.Model.html) has an event called `requestCompleted` ([link](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.Model.html#event:requestCompleted)). So you can attach a function to that event with the method `attachRequestCompleted` ([link](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.Model.html#attachRequestCompleted)):

```
this.model.attachRequestCompleted(function(oEvent){
    var model = oEvent.getSource();
    console.log(model);
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I already saw that method, but your example clarified everything.

Comment: I have a similar problem like the OP. How should I use `attachRequestCompleted` in context of `_handleRouteMatched` ?

Comment: @SDD64 I know your question is old now but...were you trying to load a model on routing to a new view ?